# Disk turns read-only while running sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, readonly

I just installed `Ubuntu 16.04.1` and was trying to run,

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

Anytime i do this, the upgrade stops and the disk turns to read only mode.

Answer (score 1):

> Anytime i do this, the upgrade stops and the disk turns in read-only

That means either your filesystem is corrupt or your disk is faulty.